# Still can't create an AAG listener

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, listener, domain

I just built a test cluster with 2 MS SQL Server 2014 machines, 1 domain controller, an 1 file share witness. (All of them are Windows2016-based.)
The 2 MS SQL Server machines are a WSFC members.

When I created the Always On Availability Group, all steps succeeded except creating a listener.

If I try to repeat adding a listener to this AAG, I receive a message:

> **Cluster network name resource 'myaag_mylistener'** failed to create its
> associated computer object in domain 'mydomain.lan' during: Resource
> online.
>
> The text for the associated error code is: Access is denied.
>
> Please work with your domain administrator to ensure that:
>
> - The cluster identity 'MYWSFC$' has Create Computer Objects permissions. By default all computer objects are created in the same
>   container as the cluster identity 'MYWSFC$'.
> - The quota for computer objects has not been reached.
> - If there is an existing computer object, verify the Cluster Identity 'MYWSFC$' has 'Full Control' permission to that computer object using
>   the Active Directory Users and Computers tool.

What I tried:

1. Create a computer object: mydomain.lan/Computers/mylistener and give the mydomain\MYWSFC$ "Full control" on it;
2. Remove the object mydomain.lan/Computers/mylistener and grant the mydomain\MYWSFC$ account permissions to create computer objects within mydomain.lan/Computers (List contents, Read all properties, Read permissions, Create computer objects);
3. In ADSI Edit, DC=mydomain,DC=lan: ms-DS-MachineAccountQuota raised from 10 to 15 (although there are only 5 machine accounts including mylistener$).

What could still be wrong?

Comment: What about "Cluster network name resource" in the error message: shouldn't it be the cluster name, such as mycluster.mydomain.tld? (Or "mycluster$" as the short form) (Which is also an additional computer object in AD and A record in DNS for the machine that currently hosts the cluster) But what I get here is a combination of the AAG name and the listener name. Is it how it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by limited resources (CPU, RAM) of my test environment. When I repeated this setup in a cloud with ample resources, the problem disappeared.